# Using the Reader monad with QuickCheck / monadicIO

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, reader-monad

I'd like to pass an integer as a CLI argument to a Haskell program that makes use of QuickCheck / `monadicIO`. That integer is going to be used inside the `assert` to make the tests customizable.
The problem is that once I parse the integer value in `main`, I don't know how to pass it inside of the `monadicIO` call without using something as ugly as an `IORef`. I would think that an elegant solution might be the `Reader` monad, but I couldn't find a solution to make it work, seen as `quickCheck` is rigid in its arguments.
Any ideas?

**Later Edit 1:** As requested, I'm attaching the actual code I'm trying this on, and failing. The commented-out lines represent my failed attempt. Background: the test suite is intended to exercise a very simple remote endpoint that computes the SHA512 of the randomized input generated by QuickCheck. The remote endpoint is Python/Flask based.

**Later Edit 2 in response to @user2407038:** I could make `propHasExpectedLengthCeiling` take an additional argument of type Int, but `quickCheck` would generate random values for it, and that's not what I want happening. My goal is to use the `maxSegmentLengthCeiling` that I'm taking in from the command-line arguments and use it in `let testPassed = actualMaxSegmentLength <= maxSegmentLengthCeiling` inside of the `monadicIO` block. Right now `maxSegmentLengthCeiling` is specified as a top-level value, which means I have to recompile the code every time I change the value. I don't yet have any code that involves `IORef` because that's a last resort and the essence of my question is how to avoid going the `IORef` route.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as LC

import Control.Applicative     ( (<$>) )
import Data.Function           ( on )
import Data.List               ( groupBy )
import Data.Char               ( isDigit )
--import Safe                    ( headMay
--                               , readMay
--                               )
--import System.Environment      ( getArgs )
import Network.HTTP.Conduit    ( simpleHttp )
import Test.QuickCheck         ( Arbitrary
                               , Property
                               , arbitrary
                               , choose
                               , frequency
                               , quickCheckWith
                               , stdArgs
                               , vectorOf
                               )
import Test.QuickCheck.Test    ( Args
                               , maxSuccess
                               )
import Test.QuickCheck.Monadic ( assert
                               , monadicIO
                               , run
                               )

newtype CustomInput = MkCustomInput String deriving Show

instance Arbitrary CustomInput where
  arbitrary =
    let
      genCustomInput = vectorOf 20
                       $ frequency [ (26, choose ('0','9'))
                                   , (10, choose ('a','z'))
                                   ]
    in
      MkCustomInput <$> genCustomInput

maxSegmentLengthCeiling :: Int
maxSegmentLengthCeiling = 22

urlPrefix :: String
urlPrefix = "http://192.168.2.3:5000/sha512sum/"

propHasExpectedLengthCeiling :: CustomInput -> Property
propHasExpectedLengthCeiling (MkCustomInput input) = monadicIO $ do
  testPassed <- run $ do
    response <- simpleHttp $ urlPrefix ++ input
    let stringResponse = LC.unpack response
    let brokenDownStringResponse = groupBy ( (==) `on` isDigit ) stringResponse
    let actualMaxSegmentLength = maximum $ map length brokenDownStringResponse
    let testPassed = actualMaxSegmentLength <= maxSegmentLengthCeiling
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn $ "Input:       " ++ input
    putStrLn $ "Control sum: " ++ stringResponse
    putStrLn $ "Breakdown:   " ++ show brokenDownStringResponse
    putStrLn $ "Max. length: " ++ show actualMaxSegmentLength
    putStrLn $ "Ceiling:     " ++ show maxSegmentLengthCeiling
    putStrLn $ "Test result: " ++ if testPassed then "Pass" else "Fail"
    putStrLn ""
    putStrLn ""
    return testPassed
  assert $ testPassed

customArgs :: Args
customArgs = stdArgs { maxSuccess = 1000000 }

--readMayAsInt :: String -> Maybe Int
--readMayAsInt = readMay

main :: IO ()
main =
--main = do
--  cliArgs <- getArgs
--  let ceilingInputMay = headMay cliArgs >>= readMayAsInt
--  maxSegmentLengthCeiling <- case ceilingInputMay of
--                               (Just lengthCeiling) -> return lengthCeiling
--                               Nothing              -> error "No valid number given"
  quickCheckWith
    customArgs
    propHasExpectedLengthCeiling
```

Comment: Some examples of what exactly you tried (and how they didn't work) would be helpful and would better illustrate what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Where exactly would you like to use `cliArgs` or any other input? Could you make `propHasExpectedLengthCeiling` take an additional argument (` :: Int -> CustomInput -> Property`)? I don't know how `IORef` factors into this at all. Could you clarify that, or include the code that uses `IORef`, or code that doesn't compile, but looks something like what you would want to have?

Comment: @user2407038, please see later edit 2.

Comment: @Toshio Make the `Int` a parameter to `propHasExpectedLengthCeiling ` and invoke it as `main = do [n] <- getArgs; quickCheckWith customArgs (propHasExpectedLengthCeiling (read n))`. What am I missing here?

Comment: @user2407038, yes, somehow that didn't occur to me. Please copy/paste your comment in the form of an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `maxSegmentLengthCeiling` a parameter to `propHasExpectedLengthCeiling` :

```
propHasExpectedLengthCeiling :: Int -> CustomInput -> Property
```

and invoke it as

```
main = do 
  [n] <- getArgs
  quickCheckWith customArgs (propHasExpectedLengthCeiling (read n))
```